# Guard/LiveReload/Sass/Compass CSS Caching Issue

Tags: theming

Here is a quick primer on my setup.

Running an aurora sub theme that utilizes guard, guard compass, guard livereload.

Basically what is happening is I make a change in a sass file, the files compile and the style change is shown right away on the browser. Great.

The problem arises when I click a link to go to another page, the CSS that is on the newly visited page is from the previous state. So my test cases are.. change the background color from blue to red. Background changes to red on the screen. Click a link to another node, background remains blue. Simple browser refresh, background turns to red.

I've been trying to find some info on this specifically, but having a heck of a time.

Things I've tried so far

1. Turn off sass caching in my config.rb file, so no .sass-cache generation {:cache => false}.
2. Reference my stylesheet via a hard coded entry in the html.tpl.php template instead of via the info file.
3. Tried a basic 2 .html page test case, nothing to do with drupal, and I get the results I wanted (no css cached).
4. I've even looked at Chrome settings before really deciding I felt this is a Drupal thing.
5. I made a color change, watched the result in my browser, went into the sites/default/files/css/ directory and deleted all the css files, went back to my browser and clicked on a link to another node, and the same result happened, previous CSS rendering.
6. Did the same thing above except instead of deleting CSS files from the folder, I just ran a drush cc css-js in terminal, then went and visited the second node link, and still old CSS renders.
7. I have not implemented this, but I know I can run drush commands via guard shell and was wondering if I can do the above in 6, just automate it.
8. Messed around with config.rb settings such as debug, line_comments, environment or production variables, etc.

I am running out of ideas on how to get this to work a bit better.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are some other people here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1990926 having similar issues.

Make sure that you don't have caching and or Aggregation turned on when developing. These settings can be changed under configuration > development > performance.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have scss files in your LiveReload "files to watch" option, this will ensure your changes apply from node to node, without having to manually refresh just because you changed pages. Not sure of any side effects as of yet.